# Jquery stop sound-cloud embed modal

Tags: jquery, soundcloud

Stopping sound-cloud when closing modal. Is there an HTML or JQuery solution? I tried this. However I can not get it to function. Is there something I am overlooking with my code? it seems like the variables are messing up the code, yet i don’t know why...

**Code:**

```
<div class = "modal fade" id = "seeyou" role= "dialoge">
  <div class = "modal-dialog">
    <div class = "modal-content">
      <div class= "modal-header">
          <h4>GUEST LIST</h4>
            <div id = "video">
                 <iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/199607357&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>
             </div>
            <div class = "modal-footer">
              <a class = "btn btn-default" data-dismiss = "modal">CLOSE</a>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js"></script>
    <script src="copy.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box-toggle3').hide();
    $('.box-toggle1').hide();
    $('.box-toggle2').hide();

    var iframeElement   = $('#video > iframe')[0];
    var scPlayer = SC.Widget('iframeElement');
    $('#seeyou').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    scPlayer.pause();
            });

    $('#new-releases').click(function() {
        $('#box').removeClass('box-reg');
        $('#box').addClass('box-zoom');
        $('.box-toggle1').fadeOut(200);
        $('.box-toggle3').fadeOut(250);
        $('.box-toggle2').fadeOut(250);
        $('.box-toggle').fadeOut(250);
        $('.box-toggle1').fadeIn(2500);
    });

    $('#concerts').click(function() {
        $('.box-toggle3').fadeOut(250);
        $('.box-toggle2').fadeOut(250);
        $('.box-toggle1').fadeOut(200);
        $('.box-toggle').fadeOut(250);
        $('#box').removeClass('box-zoom');
        $('#box').addClass('box-reg');
        $('.box-toggle2').fadeIn(2500);
    });

    $('#playlists').click(function() {
        $('.box-toggle3').fadeOut(250);
        $('.box-toggle2').fadeOut(250);
        $('.box-toggle1').fadeOut(200);
        $('.box-toggle').fadeOut(250);
        $('#box').removeClass('box-zoom');
        $('#box').addClass('box-reg');
        $('.box-toggle3').fadeIn(2500);
    });

    $('#news').click(function() {
        $('.box-toggle').fadeOut(250);
        $('.box-toggle3').fadeOut(250);
        $('.box-toggle2').fadeOut(250);
        $('.box-toggle1').fadeOut(200);
        $('#box').removeClass('box-zoom');
        $('#box').addClass('box-reg');
        $('.box-toggle').fadeIn(2500);
    });

    $('#news2').click(function() {
        $('.box-toggle3').fadeOut(250);
        $('.box-toggle2').fadeOut(250);
        $('.box-toggle1').fadeOut(200);
        $('.box-toggle').fadeOut(250);
        $('#box').removeClass('box-zoom');
        $('#box').addClass('box-reg');
        $('.box-toggle2').fadeIn(1500);
    });

    $('#news3').click(function() {
        $('#box').removeClass('box-reg');
        $('#box').addClass('box-zoom');
        $('.box-toggle1').fadeOut(200);
        $('.box-toggle3').fadeOut(250);
        $('.box-toggle2').fadeOut(250);
        $('.box-toggle').fadeOut(250);
        $('.box-toggle1').fadeIn(1500);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

**[SoundCloud's public API](https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js)** can be used to control the player.

```
var iframeElement   = $('#video > iframe')[0]; // catches the iframe element
var scPlayer         = SC.Widget(iframeElement); // wraps with SoundClouds api

$('#myModal1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    scPlayer.pause(); // pause the player when the modal window is closed.
})
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/h3WDq/540/**

Comment: Maybe I’m overlooking something. When i add this to my code it doesn’t complete the task.                                                                                                 var iframeElement = $('#video > iframe')[0]; // catches the iframe element
 var scPlayer = SC.Widget('iframeElement');
 $('#seeyou').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    scPlayer.pause();
      });

Comment: @RickiMoore how about something like this http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/h3WDq/543/ ? I made few changes here and there to make it work.

Comment: i think its the javascript that i don’t understand

Comment: do you see any errors in the console ? Also, can you try to replicate your code on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: When i use the two lines with the variables it stops my code

Comment: [Error] Error: SC.Widget function should be given either iframe element or a string specifying id attribute of iframe element.
 v (api.js, line 1)
 (anonymous function) (copy.js, line 7)
 j (jquery.min.js, line 2)
 fireWith (jquery.min.js, line 2)
 ready (jquery.min.js, line 2)
 J (jquery.min.js, line 2)

Comment: [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (pubmeta, line 0)
[Warning] Exception: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable. (widget-9f73fbe3.js, line 3)
[Warning] Object (widget-9f73fbe3.js, line 3)

Comment: [Error] InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.
 createPattern (single-sound-5a83c18c.js, line 56)
 y (single-sound-5a83c18c.js, line 56)
 draw (single-sound-5a83c18c.js, line 56)
 (anonymous function) (widget-9f73fbe3.js, line 74)
 update (single-sound-5a83c18c.js, line 53)
 update (single-sound-5a83c18c.js, line 52)
 (anonymous function) ([native code], line 0)

Comment: Two things: 1. Make sure the javascript code is located at the end of the page. 2. By any chance are there multiple `#video` divs ?

Comment: Yes, I have added the script at the bottom of the page. This is the only video ID that i have so far. when i remove the two lines of variables the code doesn’t break but it doesn’t stop the video. When i re-add them, the entire java in the page breaks.

Comment: can you please replicate this issue on http://jsfiddle.net ? or the just update the demo fiddle in my answer ?

Comment: i can’t get it to save

Comment: the safari won’t allow me to see the menu bar above

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work. I had to changed the variables of the IFRAMEELEMENT i was able to call the function. Thanks A lot for the help!

```
<div class = "modal fade" id = "seeyou" role= "dialoge">
  <div class = "modal-dialog">
    <div class = "modal-content">
      <div class= "modal-header">
          <h4>GUEST LIST</h4>
            <div id = "video">
                 <iframe id = "sc-widget" width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/199607357&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>
             </div>
            <div class = "modal-footer">
              <a id = "stopSound" class = "btn btn-default" data-dismiss = "modal">CLOSE</a>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
var widget1 = SC.Widget("sc-widget");
             $("#stopSound").click(function() {
            widget1.pause()
        });
             $('#seeyou').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        widget1.pause();
        });
```

Comment: technically there is no difference between `#video > iframe` and giving iframe an id. As long as it works :)